# Why passing custom object in @Input doesn't work?

Tags: angular, angular2-databinding

I am trying to pass a custom object through @Input. But, I'm getting **null** as output.

This is my child component class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Element } from '../app.element';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})
export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {
//  @Input('srvElement') element: {type: string, name: string, content: string};    <--- This works

  @Input('srvElement') ele:Element;   <--- This doesn't work

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

This is my `element` class:

```
export class Element{
  type: string;
  name: string;
  content: string;
  constructor(type: string="", name: string="", content: string=""){
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.content = content;
  }
}
```

In parent class's html ie `app.component.html`, I have this(to communicate to child class):

```
<div class="container">
  <app-cockpit (notify)="onNotifyClicked($event)"></app-cockpit>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-server-element *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
      [srvElement]="serverElement"></app-server-element>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent class ie `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Element } from './app.element';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverElements = [{type: 'server', name: 'Testserver', content: 'Just a test'}];
  element: {type: string, name: string, content: string};

  onNotifyClicked(e: Element){
    if(e.type==='server'){
        this.serverElements.push({
        type: 'server',
        name: e.name,
        content: e.content
      });
    } else {
        this.serverElements.push({
        type: 'blueprint',
        name: e.name,
        content: e.content
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Can any one please explain to me why `@Input('srvElement') ele:Element;`  **doesn't** work **nor does** `@Input('srvElement') let ele=new Element();` (Passing my own custom object) but `@Input('srvElement') element: {type: string, name: string, content: string};` just **works fine**??

Comment: please share your parent component code also

Comment: @ARUN I did just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that doing either of these two option works:

- `@Input('srvElement') element=new Element();`
- `@Input('srvElement') element:Element;`

**NOTE:** Object's name **must** be `element` as it has been used in child class's html ie `server-element.component.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an example working where I define the input as:

```
import {Element} from 'placeWhereThisIs';
...

@Input() srvElement: Element;
```

Comment: Doing this giving me `null` as output.

Answer (score 0):

you need parent element which will loop and child element is your child componenet.

```
<div *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements">
  <app-server-element 
       [srvElement]="serverElement"></app-server-element>  
</div>
```

check below line in your child component

```
ngOnChanges() {
   console.log(this.ele);
 }
```

it should work.

which ever code you write in  onNotifyClicked event put that code in ngOnChanges.

because your parent component's for loop iterate after load the child component you need notification that child component input parameter is changes that's why you need ngOnChanges event.

Comment: I did something like that. Also, when I do `@Input('srvElement') element: {type: string, name: string, content: string}`, I'm getting desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be because of `Element` type definition is also belongs to HTML elements. But I tried this in the `plunker` and worked very well. You should try after changing the name of the `Element` class. Here is the Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/RSPoEEub1mtr2BC4sqxQ?p=preview

Comment: This is not the case `element` worked just fine for me.